# Mysql Как привести строку к числу и отсортировать по убыванию?

Tags: mysql

День добрый!
Вот выполняю сл запрос:

```
  SELECT `DocNom`,`DocDate`, `DocName`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DocFile`, ':', -1) 
AS `FileSizeSort` FROM `Message2002` ORDER BY `FileSizeSort` DESC
```

В запросе выводится стока и сортируется естественно как строка. Хотел бы приводить её к числу и сортировать как число. Вот такой фрагмент не работает как нужно:

```
    SELECT `DocNom`,`DocDate`, `DocName`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DocFile`+0, ':', -1) 
AS `FileSizeSort` FROM `Message2002` ORDER BY `FileSizeSort` DESC
```

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо!

Comment: Почему аргумент суммируете, а не результат функции?

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался...
Вот так работает как надо:
 SELECT `DocNom`,`DocDate`, `DocName`, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DocFile`, ':', -1) 
AS `FileSizeSort` FROM `Message2002` ORDER BY `FileSizeSort`+0 DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться явно функцией приведения типа:

```
  SELECT `DocNom`,`DocDate`,`DocName`,SUBSTRING_INDEX(`DocFile`, ':', -1) AS `FileSizeSort`
    FROM `Message2002`
   ORDER BY CAST(`FileSizeSort` as signed) DESC
```

Хотя ваш вариант сложить с нулем то же рабочий, если ноль добавлять уже после вырезки строки: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(DocFile, ':', -1) + 0`

Comment: Спасибо! Тоже работает!